# Busca eficiente com frase e palavras-chaves

Tags: php, mysql, sql

estou usando a seguinte sintaxe no SQL para buscas:

```
SELECT * FROM exemplo WHERE MATCH(title,content,tag) AGAINST(?)
```

Em relação ao LIKE tive um resultado melhor, mas ainda não é 100%.

para efeito de testes, tenho um registro só com título com os demais campos vazios, assim:

> *vendo carro um pouco amassado nas laterais ano de 2002*

E faço a seguinte busca:

> Compro carro do ano 2002;

Mas o resultado é falso, oque posso fazer para que a busca fique mais eficiente e relacione o máximo de palavras possíveis do título mesmo que não estejam lado a lado?

Comment: Por padrão o MySQL usa o `IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE`, experimente usar o `IN BOOLEAN MODE`. Dessa forma mantenha `AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)`. Veja em https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html.

Comment: Continua na mesma, amigo, mas vou dar uma lida e pesquisada...

Comment: Achei esse artigo e ajudou bastante no resultado que eu queria http://www.hackingwithphp.com/9/3/18/advanced-text-searching-using-full-text-indexes